# removing duplicates files with CRLF using awk command

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Folks,
I have been using awk command to remove the duplicates using awk.The issue is that I am facing is because of CRLF at the end of each line. Is there a way in awk that I can discard CRLF from comparison ?

Command I used :`awk '!seen[$0]++'`

**Record**

```
HelloworldCRLF
how are youCRLF
Helloworld
```

The first and third record are same and I was expecting it to be removed. I guess since the last line doesn't have CRLF it stays in the output. I tried adding CRLF at the end of the record to make sure the awk command remove it , and it does, but at times the last record does have a CRLF and I end up with an extra blank line(Becuase I add CRLF). Is there a way to fix such situation ?

By the way, the file was generated in windows.

Comment: @WalterA that would remove `\r`s from the whole file, not just the end of each line, and in any case extra `\r`s is not the OPs problem, his problem is a missing newline (CRLF in his case) at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the CRLF sequence to the record separator:

```
awk -v RS='\n|\r\n' '!seen[$0]++' file
```

Comment: Only in GNU awk or some other non-POSIX awk that allows a multi-character RS. You can write it more concisely as `RS='\r?\n'` btw. This isn't the OPs problem, though, his problem is a missing newline (CRLF in his case) at the end of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Replace any instance of `\r` before doing the comparison.

```
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"")}; !seen[$0]++'
```

Comment: That will remove any `\r`s mid-line. You should really use `/\r$/`.  This isn't the OPs problem, though, his problem is a missing newline (CRLF in his case) at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't that Windows added CRs before every LF (as everyone else so far seemed to think), it's that your file is missing a newline (which to Windows is the CRLF combination) at the end of the file. All bets are off when running a UNIX command against a file that doesn't have a terminating newline since it's no longer a true "text file" at that point. Can you modify whatever tool is generating the file to produce a terminating newline? If not then do

```
printf '\r\n' >> file
```

before running awk or any other tool on it. THEN you can run `dos2unix` or any other suggestion to handle/remove `\r`s if necessary. For example:

```
$ cat -v file
Helloworld^M
how are you^M
Helloworld$
```

Notice the `$` which is my prompt immediately after the last `Helloworld` due to the missing newline in the file. Now:

```
$ awk -v BINMODE=3 '!seen[$0]++' file | cat -v
Helloworld^M
how are you^M
Helloworld
$
$ printf '\r\n' >> file
$
$ awk -v BINMODE=3 '!seen[$0]++' file | cat -v
Helloworld^M
how are you^M
$
$ dos2unix file
dos2unix: converting file file to Unix format...
$
$ awk '!seen[$0]++' file | cat -v
Helloworld
how are you
$
```

I have to use `-v BINDMODE=3` with gawk on cygwin above to stop lower level primitives from stripping the `\r`s before the gawk script sees them.

wrt the question in the comments, here's why you can't just run dos2unix on every file that shows up on your dodorstep. Imagine this file that uses carriage returns (control-Ms) as the Field Separator:

```
$ printf 'a\rb\r\nd\r\rf\n' > file

$ cat -v file
a^Mb^M
d^M^Mf

$ awk -v BINMODE=3 -F'\r' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print NF, i, "<"$i">"; print "----"}' file
3 1 <a>
3 2 <b>
3 3 <>
----
3 1 <d>
3 2 <>
3 3 <f>
----
```

As you can see awk correctly recognizes that each line has 3 fields and that field 3 is empty on line 1 while field 2 is empty on line 2. Now let's run dos2unix on it and try again:

```
$ dos2unix file
dos2unix: converting file file to Unix format...

$ cat -v file
a^Mb
d^M^Mf

$ awk -v BINMODE=3 -F'\r' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print NF, i, "<"$i">"; print "----"}' file
2 1 <a>
2 2 <b>
----
3 1 <d>
3 2 <>
3 3 <f>
----
```

As you can see `dos2unix` corrupted the file by stripping the empty field 3 from line 1 because when it saw `\r\n` it assumed that was a dos line ending, not a FS followed by an RS.

Comment: The file can have new line at the end as well as it might be absent. I see adding it would solve the issue, i did that but when the file already as new line then the next process which reads this treats it as an empty record. is it a good practice to do dos2unix for all files as soon as it lands in Unix ?

Comment: No because not every file uses carriage-return-then-line-feed as the Record Separator, it could just be part of the data within the file. It all depends what the carriage returns (`\r`) **mean** when they precede a line feed (`\n`) in your application. I added an example to my answer to show one reason why you can't just blindly run `dos2unix` on every file. Also, dos2unix will not solve your missing newline problem - it just strips `\r`s before `\n`s, it doesn't add missing newlines at the end of files. Google for how to deal with that.

Comment: Hang on - why did you select http://stackoverflow.com/a/38036695/1745001 as your accepted answer? The problem that answer is trying to solve (dos line endings) has absolutely nothing to do with your problem (missing newline at end of file) and wouldn't be the right solution if that was your problem.